# FQL photo created last day

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-fql

How would I be able to fetch all photos taken on Facebook exactly a day ago using FQL?

At the moment, I have:

```
SELECT src_small FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()) AND created = previousDayTimeStamp
```

However, the UNIX TIME, which comes from:

```
previousDay = [iOSCalender components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:self.currentDate];
previousDay.day = -1;

previousDate = [iOSCalender dateByAddingComponents:previousDay toDate:self.currentDate options:0];

NSString *previousDayTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",
                                 [previousDate timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

references an exact date down to the second, which is also the case for the 'created' field from FQL. Is there a way I can chop down the time so that the most granular info is the day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate the number of hours into the current day, as well as the number of minutes to the hour, and then set the opposite of that to `NSDateComponents`

```
//Note: this line changes as you'll need to get Hour and Minute units as well
previousDay = [iOSCalender components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:currentDate];
previousDay.day = -1;
previousDay.hour = (previousDay.hour * -1);
previousDay.minute = (previousDay.minute * -1);

previousDate = [iOSCalender dateByAddingComponents:previousDay toDate:currentDate options:0];

NSString *previousDayTimeStamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",
                                  [previousDate timeIntervalSince1970]];
```